# python - How to generate all possibilities of adding + and - between numbers of a vector so the sum should be positive, using backtracking

Tags: python, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

I have to make a python application that generates all possibilities of adding + and - between numbers of a vector so the sum should be positive, using backtracking. I'm writing here because I don't quite understand how to make that.

As input, my application gets a vector of integer numbers: a1, a2, ... an.

I made an example of how the backtracking should work but I don't know if it's possible to realize.

(Example) For 5 numbers:

a1 a2 a3 a4 a5

```
a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5
a1 - a2 + a3 + a4 + a5
a1 - a2 - a3 + a4 + a5
a1 - a2 - a3 - a4 + a5
a1 - a2 - a3 - a4 - a5   
a1 + a2 - a3 + a4 + a5   
a1 + a2 - a3 - a4 + a5   
a1 + a2 - a3 - a4 - a5   
a1 + a2 + a3 - a4 + a5   
a1 + a2 + a3 - a4 - a5   
a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 - a5
```

This is what I already wrote:

```
def first():
    return int(a[0])

def next(nr):
    return int(a[nr+1])

def sum(x):
    suma = 0
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        suma += x[i] 
    if(suma <= 0):
        return False
    return True

def equal(x):
    for i in range(0,len(x)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(x)):
            if(x[i]==x[j]):
                return False
    return True

def isSet(x):
    if equal(x) == False:
        return False
    return True

def consistent(x,dim):
    return isSet(x)

def solution(x,dim):
    return len(x) == dim and sum(x)

def solutionFound(x,dim):
    print(x)

def backtracking(x,dim):
    # ---idea of code that doesn't work
    x=[first()] #candidate solution
    nr = -1
    while len(x)>0:
        choosed = False
        while not choosed and x[-1] < dim and nr < dim-1:
            x[-1] = next(nr) #increase the last component
            nr += 1
            choosed = consistent(x, dim)
        if choosed:
            if solution(x, dim):
                solutionFound(x, dim)
            x.append(first()) # expand candidate solution
        else:
            nr -= 1
            x = x[:-1] #go back one component
---
a = input(">>> write numbers: ").split()
n = len(a)
backtracking([],n)
```

If you have any ideas, it might be a real help. Thank you for your time and Happy New Year!

L.E.: Thanks a lot to everyone for the answers you gave. You helped me to understand a bit more of the python language.

Comment: I don't think backtracking would work to solve this problem because you can't know the sum until all the numbers have been added-up. This means that just because an intermediate sum was negative as some point isn't enough information to determine whether what the final total will be.

Comment: @martineau--haven't tried it yet but I was thinking by precomputing the reverse cumsum of absolution values of the array element you will know if you can use a particular index with a sign of +/- before reaching the end.  Meaning if sumsofar - arr[i] + cumsum[i] < 0, then backtrack since have all the remaining elements positive will still produce a negative answer.

Comment: The aim is a bit vague,  do you mean that the sum should never be negative even for intermediary result or that the end result should not be negative @BiancaG?

Comment: @YacineMahdid the end result should not be negative. Intermediary result can be negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Searches through binary tree of (+/-) using a function search.

Precomputing the sum of absolute value from each index in the array to the end, allows terminating on intermediates nodes in the search.

That's because if sum of values so far + cumsum of values from the current index to the end of the array < 0, then we know there is not enough values in the remaining array to overcome the current negative accumuldated value.

```
def findsums(a, n = -1, sumsofar = 0, signs = [], results = [], cumsum = []):

    """
    finds additions and subtraction of array element which are >= 0
        a - input array\n        
        n - highest index element of array we\'re using on the previous iteration
        sumsofar - sum using element up to index
        signs - signs (+/-) applied to these eleemnt
        results - solutions
        cumsum - cumulative sum of elements from index i to the end of array
    """
    if not cumsum:
        # Base case getting started
        #
        # Cumulative so of a in reverse order
        cumsum = cumsum_calc(a)

        # Use the first number as-is (i.e. no +/- sign)
        signs = [''] # first element is a
        sumsofar = a[0]
        n = 0

    # terminal case
    if n >= len(a)-1:
        if sumsofar >= 0:
            # terminal case (valid solution, so add)
                results.append(signs[:])
        else:
            # invalid solution
            pass # nothing to do 
    elif n == -1 or sumsofar + cumsum[n] >= 0:
        # Viable candidate so far
        # Try +/- alternatives\n        
        # Try + sign

        signs.append(' + ')
        findsums(a, n+1, sumsofar+a[n+1], signs, results, cumsum)
        signs.pop()

        # Try '-' sign
        signs.append(' - ')
        findsums(a, n+1, sumsofar-a[n+1], signs, results, cumsum)
        signs.pop()

    else:
        # Backtrack (sumsofar + cumsum[n] < 0):
        # No valid solution going forward\n        
        # So don\'t go any further with this sequence
        pass

    return results

def cumsum_calc(arr):
    " accum sum from next index forward in the array "
    # Adepted from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-find-cumulative-sum-of-a-list/\n    
    # maximum sum of elements after i
    b = [abs(x) for x in arr]
    return [sum(b[i+1:]) for i in range(len(b)+1)]

def show_solutions(a, signs):
    " intertwines signs and array to show how they are added "
    # convert a to string, with parentheses around negative values

    converta = list(map(str, a))

    # place sign before each value in array a (converta)
    # function to generate list of sign, value pairs
    create_sign_value_pairs = lambda sign: list(zip(sign, converta))

    # Create sign/value pairs (i.e. [[('+', '(-1)'), ('+', '2')],...]
    sol_with_signs = list(map(create_sign_value_pairs, signs))

    # Convert each solution to a string
    solutions = list(map(lambda sol: ' '.join([''.join(s) for s in sol]), sol_with_signs))

    return "\t" + '\n\t'.join(solutions)

tests = [[2, 3], [-1, 2], [1], [-1], [-1, -2], [1, 2, 3, 4, -5]]
```

**Example Usage**

tests = [[2, 3], [-1, 2], [1], [-1], [-1, -2], [1, 2, 3, 4, -5]]

for t in tests:
    s = findsums(t, results = [])
    print("For array {}, solutions are:".format(t))
    print(show_solutions(t, s))

**Output**

```
For array [2, 3], solutions are:
    2  + 3
For array [-1, 2], solutions are:
    -1  + 2
For array [1], solutions are:
    1
For array [-1], solutions are:

For array [-1, -2], solutions are:
    -1  - -2
For array [1, 2, 3, 4, -5], solutions are:
    1  + 2  + 3  + 4  + -5
    1  + 2  + 3  + 4  - -5
    1  + 2  + 3  - 4  - -5
    1  + 2  - 3  + 4  - -5
    1  + 2  - 3  - 4  - -5
    1  - 2  + 3  + 4  + -5
    1  - 2  + 3  + 4  - -5
    1  - 2  + 3  - 4  - -5
    1  - 2  - 3  + 4  - -5
```

**Performance**

With: arr = [-1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1,3, 34,2,1,2,-4, -9, 2, 11]

*Using Grzegorz Skibinski (combinations approach)*

> 760 ms ± 12.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

*Current Approach (using backtracking)*

> 72.1 ms ± 2.34 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

*10X faster using backtracking as opposed to testing all the combinations*

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer and sorry it took so much time for me to respond! Now I understand backtracking and the principles of this problem better. Will help a lot when I'll recheck for exams. Thanks again and have a great day! :)

Comment: @Bianca G--glad could be of help.

Answer (score 2):

A possibility is to compute the sum just before the last element is added to the current expression list. If the sum is positive with the addition of the last value, then the expression list can be produced:

```
ops = {'+':lambda x, y:x+y, '-':lambda x, y:x-y}
def _eval(d):
   return d[0] if len(d) == 1 else _eval([ops[d[1]](d[0], d[2]), *d[3:]])

def combos(vals, l, c = []):
  if not vals:
     yield c
  else:
     for i in ['+', '-']:
        if len(c) < l-1 or _eval([*c, i, vals[0]]) > 0:
           yield from combos(vals[1:], l, c+[i, vals[0]])


print(list(combos([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5, [1])))
```

Output:

```
[[1, '+', 1, '+', 2, '+', 3, '+', 4, '+', 5], 
 [1, '+', 1, '+', 2, '+', 3, '+', 4, '-', 5], 
 [1, '+', 1, '+', 2, '+', 3, '-', 4, '+', 5], 
 [1, '+', 1, '+', 2, '-', 3, '+', 4, '+', 5], 
 [1, '+', 1, '-', 2, '+', 3, '+', 4, '+', 5], 
 [1, '+', 1, '-', 2, '+', 3, '+', 4, '-', 5], 
 [1, '-', 1, '+', 2, '+', 3, '+', 4, '+', 5], 
 [1, '-', 1, '+', 2, '+', 3, '+', 4, '-', 5], 
 [1, '-', 1, '+', 2, '+', 3, '-', 4, '+', 5], 
 [1, '-', 1, '-', 2, '+', 3, '+', 4, '+', 5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools`:

```py
import itertools

v=[3,5,-7,2,-3,1,-1]

def next_combination(v):
    v=[str(el) for el in v]
    for op in itertools.product(["-","+"], repeat=len(v)-1):
        x=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(v,op))) + [v[-1]]
        if(eval(''.join(x))>0):
            yield x

for el in next_combination(v):
    print(el)
```

Output:

```py
['3', '-', '5', '-', '-7', '-', '2', '-', '-3', '-', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '-', '5', '-', '-7', '-', '2', '-', '-3', '-', '1', '+', '-1']
['3', '-', '5', '-', '-7', '-', '2', '-', '-3', '+', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '-', '5', '-', '-7', '-', '2', '-', '-3', '+', '1', '+', '-1']
['3', '-', '5', '-', '-7', '-', '2', '+', '-3', '+', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '-', '5', '-', '-7', '+', '2', '-', '-3', '-', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '-', '5', '-', '-7', '+', '2', '-', '-3', '-', '1', '+', '-1']
['3', '-', '5', '-', '-7', '+', '2', '-', '-3', '+', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '-', '5', '-', '-7', '+', '2', '-', '-3', '+', '1', '+', '-1']
['3', '-', '5', '-', '-7', '+', '2', '+', '-3', '-', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '-', '5', '-', '-7', '+', '2', '+', '-3', '-', '1', '+', '-1']
['3', '-', '5', '-', '-7', '+', '2', '+', '-3', '+', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '-', '5', '-', '-7', '+', '2', '+', '-3', '+', '1', '+', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '-', '-7', '-', '2', '-', '-3', '-', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '-', '-7', '-', '2', '-', '-3', '-', '1', '+', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '-', '-7', '-', '2', '-', '-3', '+', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '-', '-7', '-', '2', '-', '-3', '+', '1', '+', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '-', '-7', '-', '2', '+', '-3', '-', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '-', '-7', '-', '2', '+', '-3', '-', '1', '+', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '-', '-7', '-', '2', '+', '-3', '+', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '-', '-7', '-', '2', '+', '-3', '+', '1', '+', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '-', '-7', '+', '2', '-', '-3', '-', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '-', '-7', '+', '2', '-', '-3', '-', '1', '+', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '-', '-7', '+', '2', '-', '-3', '+', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '-', '-7', '+', '2', '-', '-3', '+', '1', '+', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '-', '-7', '+', '2', '+', '-3', '-', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '-', '-7', '+', '2', '+', '-3', '-', '1', '+', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '-', '-7', '+', '2', '+', '-3', '+', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '-', '-7', '+', '2', '+', '-3', '+', '1', '+', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '+', '-7', '-', '2', '-', '-3', '-', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '+', '-7', '-', '2', '-', '-3', '+', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '+', '-7', '-', '2', '-', '-3', '+', '1', '+', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '+', '-7', '+', '2', '-', '-3', '-', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '+', '-7', '+', '2', '-', '-3', '-', '1', '+', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '+', '-7', '+', '2', '-', '-3', '+', '1', '-', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '+', '-7', '+', '2', '-', '-3', '+', '1', '+', '-1']
['3', '+', '5', '+', '-7', '+', '2', '+', '-3', '+', '1', '-', '-1']
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comments you said that the requirement for a valid sequence is that it is positive at the end of the summation. The intermediary result can be negative it doesn't matter.

Therefore, what I would do is create a binary tree with the level being equal to one variable and the binary decision being + or - the next variable (i.e. left = - and right = +). The leaf nodes will be equal to the sum of traversing each of the paths. Once such a tree is constructed the only thing you need to do is traverse the tree and get to the leaves.

This is where **backtracking** kick in because once you are at a leaf and you output a result you need to return and backtrack to test another possibility. This backtracking can be easily implemented using recursion with hitting a leave being the base case. To output the full summation at the end only you can give as a parameter a list of string corresponding to the node label and the path taken so far.

Hope it helps!